# Spring cloud - client does not fetch configuration from config file server using spring.config.import in Spring boot 2.5.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm completely stucked with a problem with my config client not fetchig configuration from config file server. I am trying to do that with "new way" using spring.config.import but it looks like I am missing something.

I have my properties files stored in a private github repository. Here is my config file server:
application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/Pavello/simple-microservices-app-config-files-repo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=//My username
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=//Here I am using my private token
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=busrefresh

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.user=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

My client application looks like this:
application.properties:

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=user-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

pom.xml dependecies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

After running my config file server I'm getting following response under /user-service/default:

```
{
"name": "user-service",
"profiles": [
"default"
],
"label": null,
"version": "889d16cb37b5467ed4546d617fc5ba8280c96f2d",
"state": null,
"propertySources": [
{
"name": "https://github.com/Pavello/simple-microservices-app-config-files-repo/file:C:\\Users\\PAWEL~1.KAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-15000982762999853489\\user-service.properties",
"source": {
"login.url.path": "/users/login",
"jwt.expiration": "864002324",
"jwt.key": "passwordpasswordpasswordblabla",
"logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter": "DEBUG",
"spring.datasource.url": "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres",
"spring.datasource.driver-class-name": "org.postgresql.Driver",
"spring.datasource.jdbc-url": "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres",
"spring.datasource.username": "postgres",
"spring.datasource.password": "postgres",
"spring.datasource.initialization-mode": "always"
}
},
{
"name": "https://github.com/Pavello/simple-microservices-app-config-files-repo/file:C:\\Users\\PAWEL~1.KAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-15000982762999853489\\application.properties",
"source": {
"login.url.path": "/users/login",
"jwt.expiration": "864002324",
"jwt.key": "passwordpasswordpasswordblabla",
"logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter": "DEBUG",
"spring.datasource.url": "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres",
"spring.datasource.driver-class-name": "org.postgresql.Driver",
"spring.datasource.jdbc-url": "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres",
"spring.datasource.username": "postgres",
"spring.datasource.password": "postgres",
"spring.datasource.initialization-mode": "always"
}
}
]
}
```

So it looks like it's fetching configuration properly but on the client side I don't these values and I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$1(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at io.github.pavello.userservice.UserServiceApplication.main(UserServiceApplication.java:13)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/' or File.separator
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferencesForFile(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:138)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

I've read a couple of similar issues related to mismatch of spring boot and spring cloud version but I suppose I'm using the newest (at the moment) version of both spring boot (2.5.6) and spring cloud (2020.0.4). I've tried to add spring cloud bootstrap dependency (although I think it's not necessary) to my user service (like some other issues suggested):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

but it didn't help either. Can anyone help please ?